# Image under a non-constant analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

If $D$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is a nonconstant analytic function on $\bar{D}$, prove that $f(\partial{D}) = \partial{f(D)}$.

**My attempt**

Since $f$ is a nonconstant analytic function on $\bar{D}$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\bar{D}$ and attain its max/min on the boundary, $\partial\bar{D}$.

Also, we know that $\bar{D}=D \cup \partial{D}$.
And, $ \partial{f(D)} = \bar f(D)-f(D) \subset f(\bar{D})-f(D) \subset f(\bar{D} -D) \subset f(\partial D)$

And, Since $f$ is continuous over D, then $f(\bar D) \subset \bar f(D)$.
Using the above fact, $$f(\partial D)=f(\bar D-D)\subset \bar f(D)-f(D)=\partial f(D)$$

Can anyone help me out whether I have done the proof correctly or not?

Comment: If D is domain the D is open and connected.Then how you are assuming D is closed?

Comment: Yeah, it should be $\bar D$ is closed.

Comment: Since $\bar D$ is closed it means $\bar{\bar{D}} = \bar D$, which is $D=\bar D$

Comment: when you say non constant analytic function on $\overline{D}$, I assume you mean analytic on a neighborhood of $\overline{D}$?

Comment: I think you have to use the maximum principle here

Comment: Can you help me with how to use that here? @Glougloubarbaki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true unless $f$ is injective and the inclusion is strict $\partial f(D) \subset f(\partial D) $ in general; see $f(z)=z(z-1)$ on the unit disc; since $f(1)=f(0)=0$, $f(1)$ is an interior point of $f(D)$ by the open mapping theorem.

Comment: Does any of the information mentioned above lead to $f$ being injective?

Comment: not that I see anything - that is an extra hypothesis

Comment: Will the maximum modulus principle be helpful?

Comment: in what sense? as noted the result is simply not true as stated - the open mapping property of holomorphic functions is more relevant here (though maximum modulus is obviously implied by it so those concepts are related)